# NullPointerException when loading a URL in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I keep getting this error...

```
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373):     at com.fttech.shoppingClass$1.onClick(shoppingClass.java:47)
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
07-31 12:15:55.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24373):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

I am implementing a onClick here...

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getUserPreference();
            shopping.loadUrl(url);



        }
    });
```

I instantiated the shopping already...

Here is the class with the loadUrl method.

```
   public class shopping_details_fragment extends Fragment{


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return(inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, container, false));
}

public void loadUrl(String url){
    WebView web = (WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsOfIem);

    web.loadUrl(url);

}
```

}

here is the XML i am using..

for details_fragment.xml i am  inflating...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <WebView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/detailsOfIem"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getView() may be null.
Does your activity load details_fragment.xml?
Is `onCreateView` called before `onClick`?

But I don't really see your class structure from these snippets.

My suggestion, without you providing the full code: add

```
Log.i("Null Test", "Is xyz null ? " + (xyz == null));
```

statements everywhere in the stack where something could cause a `NullPointerException`.